# Firestore timestamp the same day condition

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have the table with timestamp. I want to check timestamp with the same day date. If date is 21/06/2020, I want to get the same day records. That code does not work:

```
where("creation_date", "==", new Date())
```

Comment: Have you investigated at all why it does not work? You are not making a query about the same day, but about the same date/time as on your local machine, so this wont work obviously

Comment: Yes, I figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the code:

```
const startToday = new Date(),
endToday = new Date();
// Set up start date
startToday.setHours(0); 
startToday.setMinutes(0); 
startToday.setSeconds(0);
// Set up end date
endToday.setHours(23); 
endToday.setMinutes(59); 
endToday.setSeconds(59);

.where("creation_date", ">=", startToday)
.where("creation_date", "<=", endToday)
```